# Graphing two lines that count the number of occurrences by year *Python*

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line

**I'm very new to python,**

I am trying to plot the amount of 2 specific courses that a school district offered by year. I have grouped my data by year and changed the classes to 0- for one class and 1- for the other class. Ideally, what I need is the x-axis to be the year and the y-axis be the number of times that 0/1 occur for that given year.

Answer (score 0):

### Use [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

- "*...changed the classes to 0- for one class and 1- for the other class*" is not needed

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# data
random.seed(365)
data = {'class': [random.choice(['A.P. Economics - Macro', 'A.P. Economics - Micro']) for _ in range(100)],
        'year': [random.choice([*range(2000, 2021)]) for _ in range(100)]}

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# groupby, count and transform back to dataframe
t = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['year', 'class'])['class'].count()).rename(columns={'class': 'count'}).reset_index(level=1)

                       class  count
year                               
2000  A.P. Economics - Macro      1
2000  A.P. Economics - Micro      1
2001  A.P. Economics - Macro      2
2001  A.P. Economics - Micro      2
2002  A.P. Economics - Macro      3
2002  A.P. Economics - Micro      1
2003  A.P. Economics - Macro      3
2003  A.P. Economics - Micro      3
2004  A.P. Economics - Macro      4
2005  A.P. Economics - Macro      2
2005  A.P. Economics - Micro      1
2006  A.P. Economics - Macro      4
2006  A.P. Economics - Micro      1
2007  A.P. Economics - Micro      3
2008  A.P. Economics - Macro      3
2008  A.P. Economics - Micro      3
2009  A.P. Economics - Macro      2
2009  A.P. Economics - Micro      7
2010  A.P. Economics - Macro      5
2010  A.P. Economics - Micro      2
2011  A.P. Economics - Macro      4
2011  A.P. Economics - Micro      3
2012  A.P. Economics - Macro      1
2012  A.P. Economics - Micro      6
2013  A.P. Economics - Macro      2
2013  A.P. Economics - Micro      3
2014  A.P. Economics - Macro      5
2014  A.P. Economics - Micro      3
2015  A.P. Economics - Macro      1
2015  A.P. Economics - Micro      2
2016  A.P. Economics - Macro      3
2016  A.P. Economics - Micro      4
2017  A.P. Economics - Macro      2
2017  A.P. Economics - Micro      1
2018  A.P. Economics - Macro      2
2018  A.P. Economics - Micro      2
2019  A.P. Economics - Micro      1
2020  A.P. Economics - Micro      2
```

## Bar plot with seaborn

```py
sns.barplot(x=t.index, y='count', data=t, hue='class')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

## Lineplot

- However, this is not an optimal way of presenting this data.

  - It gives the impression that data is continuous, when it's discreet.
  - It's messy
  - It doesn't clearly convey information, which is the number of occurrences of a class in a given year.
  - The year is interpreted as an integer, not a datetime.

```py
sns.lineplot(x=t.index, y='count', data=t, hue='class')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment! I suppose I should have clarified that I need a line graph with two lines.